# Handling an Event Raised in a Separate DLL

Tags: c#, events, dll, event-handling

I am having some issues with handling an event that I am raising in a separate DLL in a separate exe. I have a class that subscribes to the event in another DLL. When I raise the event, by the time I get to the event handling, the event handler is null since the object that subscribed to it exists in separate call stack. Is there a clean way to handle something like this?

Public class B is in another dll on another executable (same solution) than Class A.

```
public static class CustomEvent
{
   public static event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> eventHandler;
   public static void Raise(CustomEventArgs args)
   {
      // When class B raises the event. The eventHandler here is null. 
      // Meaning it doesn't know that Class A has subscribed to the event.
      EventHandler<CutomEventArgs> handler = eventHandler; 
      if(handler != null)
      {
         eventHandler(typeof(CustomEvent), args);
      }
   }
}

public class A
{
   public class A ()
   {
      CustomEvent.eventHandler += HandleEvent;
   }



public class B
{
   public void Function()
   {
      CustomEvent.Raise(new CustomEventArgs());
   }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to show some code. What you describe _"Should just work"_. BTW, All code running on the same thread shares the same call stack.

Comment: Please show us some code you already tried.

Comment: Yep.  That code should work, and it won't matter if the classes are in different assemblies.  So try to create a minimal repro of you're issue, and you should find the problem.  Otherwise post it in your question.